# Overwrite a single value in a text file using php

Tags: php

I'm trying to write a code that is supposed to store a set number of days for an account. The user of this account is then supposed to be capable of selecting a certain timeframe using html. Then those days are supposed to be subtracted from the total amount and the new value is supposed to be put back into the text file.

So far I've tried solving a lot of this by reading the txt file into an array and working from there, but that's kind of where I run into a dead end cause I can't quite find a solution for my problem.

The way i have it working at the moment is as such:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_btn'])) //If the submit button is pressed, it starts working through the steps
                {
                    $start1 = date_create($_POST["start"]); //I convert the HTML dates to php dates so i can work with them in a second
                    $end1 = date_create($_POST["end"]);
                    $start2 = date_format($start1, "Y-m-d");
                    $end2 = date_format($end1, "Y-m-d");
                    $end = $end2;
                    $start = $start2;
                    $d_diff1 = date_diff(date_create($end), date_create($start)); //I create the date difference and convert them back into a value I can work with
                    $d_diff = $d_diff1->format('%d days');
                    $up = fopen('text\urlaub.txt', 'a+');

                    if($d_diff < 0) //The next few lines are technically irrelevant for the problem
                    {
                        echo "Ihr Startdatum muss vor dem Enddatum liegen.";
                    }
                    elseif($d_diff == 0)
                    {
                        echo "Sie können heute keinen Urlaub mehr legen.";
                    }
                    elseif($d_diff >= 35)
                    {
                        echo "Ihr Antrag wurde gestellt. Aufgrund der Länge dea Beantragten Urlaubs muss dieser erst manuell bestätigt werden. Sie werden innerhalb von 2 Werktagen benachrichtigt.<br>";
                    }
                    elseif($d_diff >= 1 && $d_diff <= 35) //Here is where the problem starts
                    {
                        echo "Ihr Antrag wurde eingereicht und von System freigegeben. Sollte es Probleme mit ihrem Antrag geben wird sich in den nächsten 2 Tagen ein Mitarbeiter an sie wenden. <br>";
                        $urlaubkey = str_word_count(file_get_contents('text\urlaub.txt'),1,'üöä1234567890-.:;_<>|@€!§%&/=?'); //I read the txt file into the array
                    }
                    $key = array_search($name, $urlaubkey); //I check for the username in the array. If I find it, the array key for the username is saved as a variable
                    echo $key; //Next step would be to increase the value of this by 1 to get the correct key. Then i'd have to overwrite the txt file.
```

This is basically where I am at now. The only other things missing is me increasing the array key by one and me running the simple substraction, but that isn't really the issue

The way my txt file saves the values is as such:

```
körner,26
werner,26
albert,30
wernher,26
Walther,34
```

It's following the scheme of 'Username','Remaining days'

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is the given format of the data in the file needed to be followed? Or is another data storage format also possible to be used, like JSON?

Comment: If I had the option i'd like to keep it as txt.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you serialize and deserialize the contents of the array containing your data using the [serialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [unserialize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) functions; that will make it easier for you to manipulate the contents of the array

Please see the following sample code

```php
<?php

define("FILENAME", "C:\TEMP\UserList.txt");

// Create an array containing a list of users 

$userList = array(
    'USER0001' => array(
        'name' => 'Fabio',
        'number' => 23,
    ),
    'USER0002' => array(
        'name' => 'Laura',
        'number' => 7,
    ),
);

// Serialize the array and write the contents to a file 

file_put_contents(FILENAME, serialize($userList));

// Read the contents from the file and deserialize the array 

$userList = unserialize(file_get_contents(FILENAME));

// Update the value of the 'number' field, identifying the user by its unique key 

$userList['USER0001']['number'] = 75;

// Write once more 

file_put_contents(FILENAME, serialize($userList));

// Read once more 

$userList = unserialize(file_get_contents(FILENAME));

// Dump the result 

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($userList);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Although serialization might work here, I can't but put the risk of security problems coming with serialization like [PHP Objection Injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/vulnerabilities/PHP_Object_Injection). To use a data storage format like JSON would separate data and code better and reduce risks about security.

Comment: @TheFRedFox, I cannot disagree! However, the question indicates that data is currently stored in files as arrays, and therefore I suggested the easiest and fastest solution. Serializing and deserializing the contents of the arrays as JSON, despite of the many advantages, would require a substantial revision of the architecture

Comment: I'll implement this tomorow (Had to send my laptop off over the weekend for repairs) and I'll see if I can get that to work. Security is also of no concern as this is only for a school project running over a local host